# CBPeripheral connection keep disconnecting after calling discoverServices

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm trying to integrate the coreBluetooth within my application. Here is my code:

```
@interface Central() <CBCentralManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral * activePeripheral;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager * centralManager;
@end

@implementation Central

- (id) init
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self)
     {
        NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @YES};
        self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self  queue:defaultGlobalQueue options:options];
     }
     return self;
}

- (void) startScanning:(NSInteger)timeout
{
    self.activePeripheral = nil;
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"A65eBB2D-3D30-4981-9DB2-1996D88118A0"]] options:nil];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    if (self.activePeripheral != nil)
    {
        return;
    }
    self.activePeripheral = peripheral;
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    [self.activePeripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"A65eBB2D-3D30-4981-9DB2-1996D88118A0"]]];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Disconnected from peripheral : %@",peripheral);
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error disconnecting peripheral: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        //[self didErrorDelegateWithPeripheral:peripheral andError:error andCode:BLE_FAILED_TO_CONNECT];
    }
}
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    //Logic here
}
```

I'm calling startScanning within a `viewcontroller` and it always enters in the `(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error` callback after calling  `[self.activePeripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"A65eBB2D-3D30-4981-9DB2-1996D88118A0"]]];`

here is the error I'm always seeing:

```
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 "The specified device has disconnected from us." UserInfo=0x175b8810 {NSLocalizedDescription=The specified device has disconnected from us.}
```

Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, we need to set the delegate of the peripheral discovered before trying to discover the services

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
peripheral.delegate = self;
    [self.activePeripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"A65eBB2D-3D30-4981-9DB2-1996D88118A0"]]];
}
```

Comment: This is not CoreBluetooth-related by the way. Always plug in event handlers before doing anything that requires them for processing - it's the same in other languages as well.